# How to use Typescript global types declarations in Vue SFC?

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

In `Vue2 + Typescript` project I have `global.d.ts` file with some types like that:

**global.d.ts**

```js
type Nullable<T> = T | undefined | null;
```

It works fine (without explicitly types export/import) when using in regular `.ts` files:

**misc.ts**

```js
const answer: Nullable<Answer> = null;
```

But it doesn't work inside `.vue` files:

**component.vue**

```html
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  data: () => ({
    answer: null as Nullable<Answer> // 'Nullable' is not defined
  })
});
</script>
```

Tripple slash thing doesn't work too:

```html
<script lang="ts">
/// <reference path="../../types/global.d.ts" />

import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  data: () => ({
    answer: null as Nullable<Answer> // 'Nullable' is not defined
  })
});
</script>
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that by adding path to my directory with `global.d.ts` file in `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "./types"
    ]
  }
}
```