# Using a global enum with TypeScript and Vue SFC

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am trying to declare an enum with TypeScript and then use it in Vue SFC. It works when using the enum e.g. `ModalType.None` in the `<template>`, but not in the `<script>`. I get this error

> 'ModalType' is not defined (no-undef) at src/components/Modal.vue:17:30:

Why is it working in the template, but not in the script? I don't want to import the type every time I use it which is why I am using `global.d.ts`.

I looked at [How to use Typescript global types declarations in Vue SFC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64662701/how-to-use-typescript-global-types-declarations-in-vue-sfc) but that solution didn't work.

**global.d.ts**

```
declare const enum ModalType {
  None,
  Success,
  Danger,
  Warning,
}
```

**Modal.vue**

```
<template>
  <div v-if="type === ModalType.None"></div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent, PropType } from 'vue';

  export default defineComponent({
    props: {
      type: {
        type: String as PropType<ModalType>,
        default: null,
      },
    },
    computed: {
      isNone(): boolean {
        return this.type !== ModalType.None;
      },
    },
  });
</script>
```